# Jquery UI Datepicker: Highlight first

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I want to add a class to the first 3 selectable days if var express is true.

the following code works but if i select a date the classes being removed

```
$datepicker.datepicker({
        dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "D", "M", "D", "F", "S"],
        beforeShowDay:$.datepicker.noWeekends,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: d,
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

            $('.delivery-date').text(dateText);

            var printReleaseDateParts =dateText.split('.');
            var printReleaseDate = new Date(printReleaseDateParts[2],printReleaseDateParts[1]-1,printReleaseDateParts[0]);
            printReleaseDate.setDate(printReleaseDate.getDate() - printRelease);
            $('.print-release-date').text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', printReleaseDate));
            $datepicker.removeClass('express');
            if (express) {
                $datepicker.addClass('express');
                $('*[data-handler="selectDay"]:lt(3)').addClass('express');
            } else {
                $datepicker.removeClass('express');
                $('*[data-handler="selectDay"]:lt(3)').removeClass('express');

            }

        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(){
            console.log('onChangeMonthYear');

        }
    });
```

the var express is set by checkbox. In the end, the User should be able to select a highlighted express-delivery-date if the checkbox is checked. the express-delivery-date is 3 days before the regular initiated first selectable day. The first selectable day is changed by the checkbox on change

```
$('input:checkbox[name=option-express]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $datepicker.addClass('express');
                var d = calculateMinDate(deliveryExpress);
                $datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate", d);
                $('*[data-handler="selectDay"]:lt(3)').addClass('express');

                express = true;


            } else {
                $datepicker.removeClass('express');
                var d = calculateMinDate(deliveryRegular);
                $datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate", d);
                $('*[data-andler="selectDay"]:lt(3)').removeClass('express');

                express = false;
            }
        });
```

only business days should be highlighted.

so what's the best practice to highlight the first days?

**EDIT:**

now i implemented a custom function for beforeShowDay but no luck. the console.log is fired four times but the class isn't added.

```
var expressDates = ["08/29/2016", "08/30/2016", "08/31/2016", "09/01/2016"];
function expressDays(date) {
            var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            if (noWeekend[0] && express) {
                for (var i = 0; i < expressDates.length; i++) {
                    if (new Date(expressDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                        console.log('express day!')
                        return [true, 'express', 'Express'];
                    }
                }
                return [true, ''];
            } else {
                return noWeekend;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figured it out by my self. I modified the function for beforeShowDay. i put my express date in an array and check it with $.inArray()

```
function expressDays(date) {
            var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            var expressDates = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < deliveryExpress-1; i++) {
                expressDates.push(moment($datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate")).businessAdd(i).format('L'))
            }

            if (noWeekend[0] && express) {
                var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                if($.inArray(dateString,expressDates) >=0){
                    return [true, 'express', 'Express'];
                }else{
                    return [true, 'noexpress'];
                }
            } else {
                return noWeekend;
            }
        }
```